# What is an unbounded Möbius strip called and can it be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: general-topology, terminology

The background to this question is a comment which I added at the end of [one of my answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4724327), where I discussed the impossibility of the existence of an aperiodic set of tiles for a manifold which was what I would call an unbounded [Möbius strip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_strip). To try to be more precise (as prompted by Thomas Andrews), something like ${S^1}\times\mathbb{R}$ but not really $S^1$ in the usual sense because instead $(0, y)$ is identified with ("glued to" ?) $(\epsilon,-y)$. As noted by Thomas and Ted Shifrin, this is probably better described as ${S^1}\times\mathbb{R}/\sim$ where $(x,y)\sim(-x,-y)$.

I do not manage to find a good term for such a manifold after searching with various terms like "unbounded Möbius strip", "infinite Möbius strip", etc. A ["Möbius plane"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_plane) turns out to exist but is not at all what I am looking for. So the first part of my question asks if there is an accepted name for such a manifold. (As noted in the comments by user "ronno", this is usually called the *open* Möbius strip/band.)

This manifold can easily be embedded (with closed embedding) into $\mathbb{R}^2\times{S^1}$ but I fail to see how it could have a closed embedding into $\mathbb{R}^3$. Is such an embedding (or the impossibility thereof) known?

Comment: By embedding, you mean a *closed* embedding. That is an important technical distinction.  The Möbius strip certainly embeds in $\Bbb R^3$ (and is diffeomorphic to the creature you are thinking of).

Comment: Presumably, you mean by the infinite Mobius strip $S^{1}\times \mathbb R/\sim$ where $(x,y)\sim (-x,-y)?$

Comment: Your edit gives the same thing as @Thomas's construction. Note that his equivalence relation operates on all of $S^1\times\Bbb R$. This makes it a line bundle on $\Bbb RP^1 \approx S^1$.

Comment: FYI this space is usually called the *open* Möbius strip/band. A closed embedding of a non-compact space into $\mathbb{R}^n$ is forced to be unbounded by the Heine-Borel theorem.

Comment: @ronno Thanks. It probably should have been obvious I should have looked in the direction of topological terminology. It's a bit embarrassing that I never formally studied topology, to the extent that the only text I remember reading was the Schaum's outline on it.

Answer (score 3):

There is, not surprisingly, a generalization of the usual Jordan-Brouwer separation result that a *compact* (smooth) hypersurface of $\Bbb R^n$ must be orientable (see, for example, Guillemin and Pollack). Here is Samelson's [beautiful little proof](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1969-022-01/S0002-9939-1969-0245026-9/S0002-9939-1969-0245026-9.pdf) that the same is true of a non-compact *closed* smooth submanifold. His intersection theory argument is very much the argument I learned in graduate school that a compact (smooth) hypersurface in *any simply connected manifold* must in fact be orientable. In sum, there is no smooth closed embedding of the infinite Möbius strip in $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: Interesting. This is the first time I've heard about "transversality" so it will take me a while to finish understanding the proof. Don't worry, I'm working on it, and will accept your answer as soon as I finish.

Comment: It’s a beautiful argument. Definitely read Guillemin and Pollack for a solid foundation on transversality and intersection numbers.